# Find the shortest path through a store

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, shortest-path, dijkstra

I'd like an algorithm to calculate the shortest path through a store while passing through a predetermined set of points.

So for example: My targets are Milk and Eggs and I want the shortest path through the store while picking up these items.

Formally the requirements for the algorithm are as follows:

- Start at Entrance
- End at Exit
- Pass through a predetermined set of points in the store
- Path must optimal or close to optimal

I started off by visualizing this problem as a graph where the shelves of the items are the vertices in the graph and the paths through the store are the edges. The graph is weighted by distance.

The following is a store represented as a graph, A is the entrance and F is the exit (I left out the weights in this example):

[image]

How can the shortest path be calculated from A to F whilst also passing through C and D? (C and D can be visited in any order)

An idea I had was to use Dijkstra's Algorithm to find the shortest path from A to C and then from C to D and then from D to F. However I think this solution may fail in larger graphs. Does an algorithm exist which solves this problem?

Comment: Can you pass through C and D in any order?  That makes finding the optimal path trickier.

Comment: Yes, I don't really care if I visit C or D first or second.

Comment: Forcing visits of certain nodes reduces this to the Traveling Salesman problem -- open loop version. Don't count on finding an efficient algorithm (like Dijkstra). You will use heuristics for a large number of nodes, and can brute force for smaller instance.

Comment: Shortest path through a store is usually going up and down the aisles, skipping aisles that don't have any desired products. Converting the problem to a graph discards useful information about the layout of the store.

Comment: All of my local markets have changed from undirected graphs to directed graphs.

Comment: I am not sure it is optimal but I do it in consecutive BSF runs and accumulate the path: 1. From A search either C or D 2. Depends on which you found : search from C to D or D to C. 3. Search F